# XSDObjectGen.exe vs XSD.exe

Tags: .net, xsd, xsd2code, xsdobjectgen

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between XSDObjectGen.exe & XSD.exe?

Is there any way to make XSDObjectGen.exe work in dot net 2.0?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As an alternative, there's [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/). Some features:

- Generate partial class.
- Support generic and custom collection (List, ObservableCollection, MyCustomCollection).
- Support automatic properties when no special get or set is required.
- Can generate WCF attributes (DataContract/DataMember).
- Support nillable type.
- Mask private field in IDE (use EditorBrowsableState.Never attribute).
- Generate object allocation in constructor.
- Implement INotifyPropertyChanged for enable DataBinding for wpf or Silverlight.
- Improves productivity with visual studio add-in.
- Generate summary documentation from xsd annotation.
- Check if the new and old values int setter are the same before raising property changed event.
- backup options generation in cs or vb header.
- Save and load Xml document into isolated file storage for silverlight app (new in 3.0).
- Generate CS, VB or CPP code.
- Serialize/deserialize object.
- Save into file and load from file.
- Include Xsd2CodeCustomTool.

Comment: I was looking for a way to get xsd.exe to generate shorthand properties. Although that's not possible, Xsd2Code will do it piece-meal (use xsd.exe to turn .xml into .xsd, then Xsd2Code to generate the C# class). Thanks.

Comment: This is great information, but it is not clear to me how it answers the question. (Maybe the question should be modified).

Comment: @Kirk It is a (far) better solution to creating classes from an XSD than either of the tools mentioned in the question.

Comment: What if two XSDs MyClass1.xsd and MyClass2.xsd. Both objects MyClass1 and MyClass2 both reference MyClass3. Does it create a MyClass3 objects for each type or does it detect the type already exists?

Comment: @Rhyous MyClass1.xsd and MyClass2.xsd need a reference to MyClass3.xsd (otherwise the xsd is incorrect). You run xsd2code on each xsd individually (i.e. MyClass1.xsd and MyClass2.xsd). It then creates a single file (in each run) with a class for each type/element found in the xsd, as well as any required types in the referenced XSDs.

So to answer your question: It will create the MyClass3 class twice (once in each generated file). If the XSDs are in the same place, then the namespace will be the same => delete one of the generated MyClass3.

Comment: @Rhyous If you have a MyClasses.xsd, which include and reference MyClass1 and MyClass2, then the generated file (when running xsd2code on MyClasses.xsd) should have only one definition of MyClass3.

Answer (score 8):

The difference is:

- The [XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=VS.100).aspx) (`xsd.exe`) is part of the Visual Studio SDK and has basic functionality.
- The [XSD Sample Code Generator Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=89e6b1e5-f66c-4a4d-933b-46222bb01eb0&displaylang=en) (`XSDObjectGen.exe`) is a more fully featured tool with more advanced features, and is released separately.

To give you some idea, here is a summary feature list for `XSDObjectGen.exe`:

- Support for the most popular XML schema constructs
- Enumerator and Collection behavior for repeating elements
- Programming model that matches schema
- Automatic sub-class construction
- Name collision avoidance
- Visual Studio IDE integration
- Special handling logic for DateTime types
- Multipart schema support
- XML namespace serialization
- Optional and Sequence support
- Choice Support
- Substitution group
- MakeSchemaCompliant method
- Non-optional reference-type handling
- WS-I.org basic profile compliance
- Multi-programming language support
- Depth-wise Traversal Events

For more details on these features see the *XSDObjectGen.doc* documentation file (available in `C:\Program Files\XSDObjectGenerator` after you install the tool).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you can use it with VS2005 at least (according to [this article, anyway](http://brianscodeextreme.blogspot.com/2006/01/code-camp-part-1-corrections.html))

Just add it to your External Tools collection of VS2005 under "Tools>>External Tools...".

Set your parameters as the following

- For VB: $(ItemPath) /l:vb
  /f:$(ItemFileName).vb /c /d /t
- For C#: $(ItemPath) /l:cs
  /f:$(ItemFileName).vb /c /d /t

It does appear that XSD and XSDObjectGen will yield different classes.  In fact, comments in this Rick Strahl article say "**they yield *very* different classes**" in the [article here](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/10402.aspx).

Comment: How interesting ... a downvote?  Please provide an explanation if my answer was confusing or misleading.  I'm sure other readers would like to benefit.

Answer (score 3):

At a purely technical level:

XSD.exe  uses `Arrays`
XSDObjectGen     takes a tiny step ahead and uses `ArrayLists`.
XSD2Code ***leaps ahead*** with usage of `Generics`.

If you're using .NET 2.0 and above using XSD2Code is most preferred.