# Creating a WCF Web Api Client

Tags: wcf, dynamic, proxy

I've been using the WCF Web Api recently and i've been using the WCF Web API Test Client that is built in to it to test my created webservices.

I am wanting to create a proxy in code built off of the interface rather than run svcutil.exe to create a proxy.

My webservice is working fine, however when I use fiddler to examine the message that is sent, it is putting in a namespace into the xml message.

Below is the code I use to send the request.

```
        RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest
                                              {
                                                  Email = "test@test.com",
                                                  Firstname = "firstname",
                                                  Lastname = "lastname",
                                                  Password = "password"
                                              };


        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IAccountApi>(new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost/WebServices/api/account");
        factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        proxy.Register(registerRequest);
```

This request below is generated via the client, and it fails, returning a 500 internal server error

```
<RegisterRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceModel.Accounts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Email>test@test.com</Email><Firstname>firstname</Firstname><Lastname>lastname</Lastname><Password>password</Password></RegisterRequest>
```

Using the same headers when I send using the api test client the following message passes

```
<RegisterRequest><Email>test@test.com</Email><Firstname>firstname</Firstname><Lastname>lastname</Lastname><Password>password</Password></RegisterRequest>
```

The only difference being the namespace has been removed.

Some final points,

1) If I were able to remove this namespace the request would work

2) I am not sure if ChannelFactory can be used in conjunction with WCF Web Api.  The reason being http://wcf.codeplex.com/releases/view/73423 states "[ServiceContract] is no longer required on the Web API class definition", yet Channel Factory requires it.

3) All the examples so far from the WCF Web API look like the following

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

```
Contact contact = new Contact() { Name = name };
var response = client.Post("http://localhost:9000/api/contacts/",
    new ObjectContent<Contact>(
        contact, JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType));
```

Should I be using HttpClient for my requests instead of channel factory?

Regards,
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using HttpClient class, it allows GET, POST, PUT and DELETE which was fine for WCF Web API (now called http://www.asp.net/web-api)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx

as far as building a rest proxy using codegen or being dynamic see this article 
[ReST Proxy Object Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097222/rest-proxy-object-generator)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the IAccountApi, which you do not show, is defining a namespace for the service contract.  If you really want an empty namespace (not best practice) try something like this:

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace="")]
 public interface IAccountApi
 { ... }
```

If the namespace is not defined for IAccountApi, check the [DataContract] of RegisterRequest.

Comment: Hi Richard, even with the namespace taken out it still puts xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance into the request which causes issues.