# ASP.NET web api: documenting/specifying a service

Tags: json, soap, xsd, asp.net-web-api

I've been looking at [asp.net Web Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api), and I like the simplicity of implementing a practical web service.

However, how can I document/specify the interface of a service implemented like that?  For example, is there any spec I can pass on or generate to a Java guy with no .NET background that will let him easily call and consume the service?  What can I give to the javascript guy?

Ideally, I'd like the benefits of SOAP/XSD or something like it (easy to deserialize with nicely typed objects) for the java guy, while retaining a service that's callable from a web browser too (i.e. supports non-crufy JSON).

### Update

It's worth noting that since I originally posted this question, I discovered [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/) which deals with this more naturally; supporting JSON, SOAP, and WSDL out of the box for the same service, as the client chooses.  If you really want SOAP+JSON, it may be a better framework than ASP.NET Web Api.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update March 2016**

It has been a while since this was answered and the tooling for documenting any Rest API has come along a lot. We are currently evaluating [Swagger 2.0](http://swagger.io/) now spawning out to the the [Open Api Initiative](https://openapis.org/), [RAML](http://raml.org/) and [API Blueprint](https://apiblueprint.org/).

For WebAPI projects there is a tool [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) that auto creates Swagger (Open API) format documentation.

**Format for documenting a REST service:**

There are some attempts at structuring and standardising the description of REST services:

- Web Application Desciption Language ([WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language))
- Web Service Description Language 2.0 ([WSDL 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/))

I think it is fair to say neither of the two approaches above have very wide adoption, but WADL does look like a nice concise format - a quick XSLT over the top and it could be a nice human readable format. There lots of examples of WADL for some famous API's at the apigee github site [here](https://github.com/apigee/wadl-library).

When trying to find a documentation format that is appropriate I tend to look for "inspiration" from others.... Apigee do a lot of research in this area and have this as documentation for one of their API's [here](http://apigee.com/docs/usergrid/content/app-services-resources) or take a look at Facebook's social graph api [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

The examples are largely in line with the advise [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1390-how-to-document-restful-web-services/)

**How to auto document:**

Using .NET: There is a good example of auto generating a WebApi "help" page [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/05/21/asp-net-web-api-generating-a-web-api-help-page-using-apiexplorer.aspx). A logical extension of this example may be to get it outing a WADL formated version as well...

Using Java: [Jersey](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/WADL) is a tool used in the Java community to generate WADL automatically.

**What to share with the other developers:**

Your Javascript guy will most likely want a manual like the Facebook and apigee one; giving the dev examples of the resources, urls, response codes etc. The most important thing here will be supporting JSON as the primary content type this will be the easiest for him/her to consume and work with by far.

Your Java guy would also want the manual, but also in theory they could be given example XSD for any XML representations of the resources you send/consume (assuming they make the request as "Content-Type: appplication/xml"). This **may** help them build proxy classes etc. JSON to Java and .NET converters are available online and given the example resources in your manual they should simply be able to use one of these types of services to quickly create proxies. [Generate Java class from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957406/generate-java-class-from-json).

If you absolutely must have auto discovery, auto proxy generation etc then you may need to offer a choice of **both** REST and SOAP (with WSDL) endpoints - relevant question here: [ReST Proxy Object Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097222/rest-proxy-object-generator).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `IApiExplorer` interface and `ApiExplorer` class in order to create a help page for your Web Api service. This help page will describe the REST methods exposed by your service so any developer who understands how REST works will be able to use it (regardless the language). Please read below links for details and samples:

- [ASP.NET Web API: Introducing IApiExplorer/ApiExplorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/05/13/asp-net-web-api-introducing-iapiexplorer-apiexplorer.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Web API: Generating a Web API help page using ApiExplorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/05/21/asp-net-web-api-generating-a-web-api-help-page-using-apiexplorer.aspx)
- [Documenting your ASP.Net Web API’s](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/08/01/documenting-your-asp-net-web-apis/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip to IApiExplorer - that's a good starting point!