# Does .Net have an analog of Java Apache Digester?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing

Could you please say me is there analog of Apache Digester but for .net?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the built in [Xsd tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx) that you can use, but you might want to consider looking at something like [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/).  I've not used Xsd2Code too heavily, but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289335/xsdobjectgen-exe-vs-xsd-exe) seems to recommend it over the built in Xsd.

Comment: Thanks, I saw and started creating some analog of Digester on .net currently I have first version of it. Maybe I'll publish this project on the Codeplex.