# vs2010 xsd.exe tool auto

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i'm using xsd tool from console, to make classes from xsd scheme, is there any plugin for vs2010: when i'm changing scheme, classes changes automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a plugin but you could add an External Tool in visual studio to call xsd.exe with the path to the files - see this [blog for an intro](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/07/24/using-external-tools-vstiptool0059.aspx)

See also this [question which has some instructions for doing this in vs2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289335/xsdobjectgen-exe-vs-xsd-exe)