# is there a xsd.exe alternative with restriction support?

Tags: xsd.exe, restriction

I have generated some classes using the VS 2010 version of XSD.exe.  This works well for the class relationships, but it does not support restrictions other than choices.  I need support for maxLength and pattern.  Is there an alternative tool that will generate classes with support for maxLength and pattern?

Comment: Use xsdToCode, this may work for you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289335/xsdobjectgen-exe-vs-xsd-exe