# Store xml in C# class field

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest, xml-parsing

I have a requirement like i need to write an entity class in C# which can hold xml data.
I want to avoid overhead of checking the well-formedness of saved xml.
I have a corresponding column with type XML. Do we have xml data type or some class which can be used as a class field to hold xml.
Thanks in advance

Update: The service using this Entity class is `WCF` service and in future we are making it `REST` compatible. Will `XmlDocument` or `XElement` work with it?

Comment: What about a string?

Comment: There are classes like `XDocument` and `XmlDocument` for XML data, but they require proper XML data.

Comment: Are you looking for [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)?

Comment: `XElement` can deal without a complete document, but still requires well formed XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways, two of which are `string` and [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

`string` would be 'easier' for fragments and not-well-formed XML, but `XmlDocument` can be configured with options to allow fragments; you'll have more trouble with ill-formed data though.

Answer (score 0):

**if you describe your object in a XSD file you can get a compiler to generate all your C# classes automatically and easily regenerate them when you make changes.**

This makes XML / C# a breeze. You can go to other languages too using equivilent generators.

See the tools described here: [XSDObjectGen.exe vs XSD.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289335/xsdobjectgen-exe-vs-xsd-exe)

I believe the XSD.exe tool will read in example XML and do most of the work of producing an XSD which you can refine.

If you don't need support for a fixed XML/XSD format file why can't you make any class serialize to XML by using the [Serializable] class attribute and .Net APIS to serialize/deserialize?